# Select all values by key from a nested hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, hash

I want to get the values of each key which is not nested into an array.

```
lists = {'value'=>1, 'next'=>{'value'=>2, 'next'=>{'value'=>3, 'next'=>nil}}}

def list_to_array(h)
  result = []
  h.each_value {|value|
  value.is_a?(Hash) ? list_to_array(value) :
   result << value
 }
  result
end

p list_to_array(lists)
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

wanted output [1,2,3] but I get [1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your solution, the inner `list_to_array` method call doesn't update the current result array, so it wasn't being updated correctly.
I've refactored some more stuff to make it more readable and to exclude nil values

```
lists = {'value'=>1, 'next'=>{'value'=>2, 'next'=>{'value'=>3, 'next'=>nil}}}

def list_to_array(h, results = [])
  h.each_value do |value|
    if value.is_a?(Hash)
      list_to_array(value, results)
    else
      results << value unless value.nil?
    end
  end

  results
end

p list_to_array(lists)

=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: For some stupid reasons I thought that it would be wrong to add  results variable to function arguments. It works now. 
Thank you for answer and have a great day ;)